# Super Nintendo Emulator for Android

Tags: android, emulation, nintendo

Is there any publicly available code for the Nintendo emulator? I would like to create an emulator like SNesoid for Android. Where should I start? Does this involve the NDK?

Comment: I once tried for PS1 emu but since it was already build so drop the idea by the way I think I have the code for almost all emulators except few ones btw http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_game_console_emulators check over here you can find most of info and code from here

Answer (score 3):

There's a very decent java SNES emulator called jsnes (ie. Java SNES, not to be confused with JSNES ie. JavaScript NES) developed by a user called spiller on the ZSNES board. [Here's the WIP thread](http://board.zsnes.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=13029) where the latest jar can be downloaded. It is not an open source project, to my knowledge, but it's a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

here I have found some and I prefer the first one

[bsnes](http://code.google.com/p/bsnes/downloads/list)

[snes](http://www.lysator.liu.se/snes9x/)

[zsnes](https://zsnes.bountysource.com/downloads)

Comment: all these codes are in c so to port you have to convert them into java which is really a pain if you are not comfortable with both the languages

Comment: I have seen people using the NDK to port C code to Android and then linking it to the application framework using JNI.

Answer (score 0):

You have several emulators that should try to play SNES games on your android device. For me the best emulator is [RetroArch](https://www.retrostic.com/emulators/snes/retroarch). First, try this emulator that the other ones. You have good graphics good sound and no lag which is most important. After trying the RetroArch I recommend this one Snes9x EX+. Which one you will install you would not regret.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but you can check it, the main idea is I put everything inside a browser https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview (It's very fast and powerful, so I can make bridge call between native code and JS code without any problem).

I tested it on my phone (Iphone X and Helio P90 CPU and their is no performance issue) so I think you can use it for your reference.

https://github.com/nielsezeka/flutter_snes_simulator_research